# Interação Formulario PHP e MySql não funciona

Tags: php, mysql, formulário

Amigos, estou fazendo um trabalho pro bono para um serviço público, e estou há dias tentando descobrir qual o problema do meu código. Se alguém puder me ajudar, agradeço demais.

**O formulário  é esse:**

```html
<html>

<style>

::-webkit-input-placeholder  { color:#CDCDCD; }
input:-moz-placeholder { color:#CDCDCD; }
textarea:-moz-placeholder { color:#CDCDCD; }​

</style>


<form name="saque" action="https://equadsaude.000webhostapp.com/bancodados_atualizar.php" method="POST">

<table>

<tr>
<td>Processo</td>         </tr>

<tr>
<td><input name="n1" placeholder="somente algarismos"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Valor total sacado</td>   </tr>

<tr>
<td><input name="n4" placeholder="00000.00"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Observações e Data </td> </tr>

<tr>
<td><input type="text" name="n3" ></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td col span="3"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Atualizar"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
</html>
```

**E o arquivo .php (que está no servidor local) que ele deveria chamar é esse:**

```html
<?php
if (isset($_POST["submit"])) 
{

$conectar = new mysqli("localhost","id1019345_dados_sobras","equadsaude", "id1019345_sobras");
$processo = $_POST[ 'n1' ] ;
$valor_sacado = $_POST[ 'n4' ] ;
$observacoes = $_POST[ 'n3' ] ;

//variavel de teste do POST no banco de dados
$teste = mysqli_query($conectar, "SELECT 'Processo' FROM 'Tab_Index' WHERE 'Processo' = '$processo' ");
//variavel para cálculo do Valor da Sobra no banco de dados
$sql_seleciona = mysqli_query($conectar, "SELECT 'Valor_sobra' FROM 'Tab_Index' WHERE 'Processo' = '$processo' ");
//variavel para selecao das Observacoes no banco de dados
$sql_seleciona2 = mysqli_query ($conectar, "SELECT 'Observacoes' FROM 'Tab_Index' WHERE 'Processo' = '$processo' ");

if(mysqli_num_rows($conectar, $teste) == 0)
{
echo "<p>Não existe o registro informado. Verifique novamente no Banco de Dados.</p>";  exit(mysqli_error());
}

else
{
$query1 = mysqli_query ($conectar, $sql_seleciona);
$resultado1 = $query1 - $valor_sacado;
$query2 = mysqli_query ($conectar, $sql_seleciona2);
$resultado2 = $query2."/". $observacoes;
                  
}

//Update do banco de dados
$sql_alterar = mysqli_query($conectar, "UPDATE 'Tab_Index' SET 'Valor_sobra' =  '$resultado1', 'Observacoes' =  '$resultado2' WHERE 'Processo' = '$processo' ");

if  ( isset ($sql_alterar) )
{
print "<h3> Valor da sobra atualizado com sucesso </h4>\n" ;
}
else 
{ 
print "<h3> Erro ao atualizar </h4>\n" ;
}

}
  ?>
```

Comment: Se está enviando os dados para um outro arquivo, Por que está abrindo uma condição `if (isset($_POST["submit"]))`? Ele está  impedindo de alocar as variáveis.

Answer (score 0):

Caro Danilo, já tentei retirar essa condição, e não funciona também. O erro que aparece é o mesmo:

> A página de equadsaude.000webhostapp.com não está funcionando
>
> equadsaude.000webhostapp.com não consegue atender a esta solicitação
>   no momento.
>    HTTP ERROR 500